# Вставить php-код из файла в шаблон сайта

Tags: алгоритм, php

Есть некий html код. А в нем `%pools%`.
Как из шаблона сайта выбрать `%pools%`, а на это место установить какой-то php код, который находится в каком-то файле?

`str_replace()` не подойдет, я так думаю.

---

Сейчас это реализую с помощью `explode` и `preg_match`.
Что-то подскажете?

Comment: Судя по комментарию в том числе - вы хотите из некоего шаблона при помощи PHP-скриптов генерировать новые PHP-скрипты, чтобы потом их выполнять. Если это так, то опишите подробней зачем это нужно: сдаётся мне, задача может быть решена куда проще, на уровне обычного шаблонизатора.

Comment: нет нет! Мне просто интересно как люди реализуют свой шаблонизатор.

Comment: В шаблонизаторах нет никакой необходимости менять макросы на исполняемый код (на самом деле бывает, но это такая экзотика, что в общем случае упоминать смысла нет). str_replace() на результат выполнения какого-то кода достаточно в over 9000 случаев.

Comment: Поковыряйте Twig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

str_replace вполне себе подходит для такой процедуры. Надо только вспомнить, что он умеет принимать массивы для искомого и подстановки.

```
str_replace($arr_search,$arr_replace,$subject);
```

Для облегчения процедуры создаете ассоциативный массив %переменная%=>значение, а потом делаете так:

```
str_replace(array_keys($arr_search),array_values($arr_replace),$subject);
```

preg_replace применяете после всех замен, чтобы вычистить остаточные переменные, которым не нашлось замены.

Comment: str_replace думаю не подходит, поскольку для этой функции должны быть переменные, а я хочу например вместо% pools% написать echo 2; echo 1; echo 33; и в файлик например / data / pools.php

Comment: А чего вас переменные не устраивают?

    $pools = '2'.'1'.'33'.file_get_contents('pools.php');

    $pools = '2'.'1'.'33'.(include 'pools.php');